# How can I get the product of all elements in a one dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a one dimensional NumPy array:

```
a = numpy.array([2,3,3])
```

I would like to have the product of all elements, 18 in this case.

The only way I could find to do this would be:

```
b = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, a)
```

Which looks pretty, but is not very fast (I need to do this a lot).

Is there a numpy method that does this? If not, what is the most efficient way of doing this? My real world arrays have 39 float elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In NumPy you can try:

```
numpy.prod(a)
```

For a larger array `numpy.arange(1,40) / 10.`:

```
array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,
        1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.6,  1.7,  1.8,  1.9,  2. ,  2.1,  2.2,
        2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9,  3. ,  3.1,  3.2,  3.3,
        3.4,  3.5,  3.6,  3.7,  3.8,  3.9])
```

your `reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, a)` needs 24.2µs,

`numpy.prod(a)` needs 3.9µs.

**EDIT:** `a.prod()` needs 2.67µs. Thanks to J.F. Sebastian!

Comment: A, numpy.prod(), that is what I was searching. Thanks!

Comment: [`a.prod()` is slightly faster than `np.prod(a)`](https://gist.github.com/875795)

Answer (score 0):

Or if the loss of numerical accuracy is not a problem, we can do

```
>>> numpy.exp(numpy.sum(numpy.log(a)))
17.999999999999996

>>> numpy.prod(a)
18
```

Comment: why not use `numpy.sum`?

Comment: @MSeifert thanks `numpy.sum` would be better, i just meant to save some characters :P